# Way to pull Exchange permissions

Tags: powershell, office365

Maybe an easy question for someone who knows Powershell and O365 well. Is there a way to configure it so when a command is run for example to pull all access to a shared mailbox, that either a service account is permissioned each time to pull that information or the user who is running the script? I looked at connecting an SA to the script but it would have too much access to 0365 to give it the specific permissions.  So the account is not permissioned for the access by default but every time the script/command is ran its permissioned for that inquiry which it shows then it won't have access until the next time its called.

Looking to add this type of function to a script which we only want the helpdesk people to see the information when they run the script and the specific command in the script.

Hopefully explained clear enough :)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that natively. You could fiddle something with Azure PIM but that's more for one-off operations than minute action that are done often.

You could however circumvent that by making some sort of web interface that triggers commands on another server using a privileged SA and returns the output through the web interface. You can just make it so that the interface can only request one specific command to be run, and the only thing you have to worry about is sanitizing your parameters well to avoid unwanted injection.

Alternatively, what are you trying to protect against by restricting access so much ? Isn't it something that could be done more easily using a read-only account and some clearly defined policy ? If your helpdesk people overstep their allowed scope, that's a management/HR problem as much as a technical one.

Comment: Thank you. I thought as much. Its more a restriction on roles so they shouldn't be doing things they are not provisioned for. I was hoping to avoid the SA account permissioned and run. I may as you say try the Web interface approach.... The only command it will be is checking mailbox permissions. Thank you.